# Raw ActionLink linkText

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper, actionlink

I want to put a button as the text of an `@ActionLink()` but I can't because it HTML-escapes my string... I found the `@Html.Raw()` mechanism and have tried the `@ActionLink().ToHtmlString()` but can't figure out how to put it together...

I found [an article](http://kitsula.com/Article/Html.ImageActionLink-extension) that describes building an extension for a similar purpose but it's eeky to go to that much trouble... there must be an easy way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could write a helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyActionLink(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string linkText, 
        string action, 
        string controller,
        object routeValues,
        object htmlAttributes
    )
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
        anchor.InnerHtml = linkText;
        anchor.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(action, controller, routeValues);
        anchor.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchor.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then use this helper:

```
@Html.MyActionLink(
    "<span>Hello World</span>", 
    "foo", 
    "home",
    new { id = "123" },
    new { @class = "foo" }
)
```

which given default routes would produce:

```
<a class="foo" href="/home/foo/123"><span>Hello World</span></a>
```

Comment: oh that's much better.  I wish they'd just provided a switch for the existing method.  I guess I didn't want to have to write a helper for it but your solution's pretty light.  thanks!

Comment: though, honestly, for that matter I can just do `<a href='@Url.Action()'>whatever</a>'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a custom action link that uses T4MVC library, You can write the below code:

```
    public static System.Web.IHtmlString DtxActionLink(
        this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string linkText,
        System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult actionResult = null,
        object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        System.Web.Mvc.IT4MVCActionResult oT4MVCActionResult =
            actionResult as System.Web.Mvc.IT4MVCActionResult;

        if (oT4MVCActionResult == null)
        {
            return (null);
        }

        System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper oUrlHelper =
            new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder oTagBuilder =
            new System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder("a");

        oTagBuilder.InnerHtml = linkText;

        oTagBuilder.AddCssClass("btn btn-default");

        oTagBuilder.Attributes["href"] = oUrlHelper.Action
            (oT4MVCActionResult.Action,
            oT4MVCActionResult.Controller,
            oT4MVCActionResult.RouteValueDictionary);

        oTagBuilder.MergeAttributes
            (new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));

        return (html.Raw(oTagBuilder.ToString()));
    }
```