# Getting raw text using @Html.ActionLink in Razor / MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, formatting, razor

Given the following Html.ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.dsResults.Tables[0].Rows[i]["title"].ToString(), "ItemLinkClick",
    new { itemListID = @Model.dsResults.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ItemListID"], itemPosNum = i+1 }, ...
```

Data from the model contains HTML in the title field.  However, I am unable to display the HTML encoded values.  ie. underlined text shows up with the `<u>....</u>` around it.

I've tried Html.Raw in the text part of the ActionLink, but no go.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you putting html in your model instead of your view?  If you need it to be underlined, add a style or class attibute for that.

Comment: The data coming back from the model is formatted based on keywords.  Thus, formatting is required at that level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you still want to use a helper to create an action link with raw HTML for the link text then I don't believe you can use `Html.ActionLink`. However, the answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063467/raw-actionlink-linktext) describes creating a helper which does this.

I would write the link HTML manually though and use the `Url.Action` helper which creates the URL which `Html.ActionLink` would have created:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ItemLinkClick", new { itemListID = @Model.dsResults.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ItemListID"], itemPosNum = i+1 })">
    @Html.Raw(Model.dsResults.Tables[0].Rows[i]["title"].ToString())
</a>
```

Comment: Excellent answer +1. I was looking for a non-Helper based solution throughout the web but all i was getting helper based solutions. You made my day! cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

`MVCHtmlString.Create` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using the actionlink below you do not need to pass html in the model.  Let the css class or inline style determine how the href is decorated.

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.dsResults.Tables[0].Rows[i]["title"], "ItemLinkClick", "Controller", new { @class = "underline", style="text-decoration: underline" }, null)
```

Comment: The decoration is not for the entire string, only part of it, so I don't think this will do.

Answer (score 0):

those are the cases that you should take the other path

```
@{
    string title = Model.dsResults.Tables[0].Rows[i]["title"].ToString(),
           aHref = String.Format("/ItemLinkClick/itemListID={0}&itemPosNum={1}...", 
                       Model.dsResults.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ItemListID"],
                       i+1);
}

<a href="@aHref" class="whatever">@Html.Raw(title)</a>
```

Remember that Razor helpers, help you, but you can still do things in the HTML way.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this:

```
<a class='btn btn-link' 
   href='/Mycontroler/MyAction/" + item.ID + "'
   data-ajax='true' 
   data-ajax-method='Get' 
   data-ajax-mode='InsertionMode.Replace' 
   data-ajax-update='#Mymodal'>My Comments</a>
```