# Html.ActionLink text styling

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.actionlink

I want to style only part of text inside my ActionLink, I need the plus sign to be bold. In pure html I can do it this way.

```
<a class="topMenu" href="#"><span style="font-weight:bold;">+</span>Invite User</a>
```

If try it with ActionLink like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("<span style="font-weight:bold;">+</span>Invite User", "Invite", "Account", new { @class = "topMenu" })
```

It gets rendered as it is, just as a line of text.

Is it possible to get it styled like in pure `HTML`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Raw ActionLink linkText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063467/raw-actionlink-linktext)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Url.Action`

```
<a class="topMenu" href="@Url.Action("Invite", "Account")">
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">+</span>Invite User
</a>
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Exactly what I needed.  I finally get it now.  The `@Html.ActionLink` saves you the hassle of explicitly writing the `<a>` Link out; but if you want to customize the Link-Text, then we use the `<a>` Link with `@Url.Action` instead.